# How to index properly

Tags: python

I am trying to look at individual pixel values within an image array, see if they are above a certain threshold,and find their coordinates if they meet this condition. I am having trouble with properly indexing each pixel within a for loop. The image in question is the first slice of a data cube called mkv_array with a size (1080,1920,500).
I am finding stars within a star field, so the threshold that has to be met is based on the background levels in the image and the statistic noise (found with 'sep' function).

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/jryan/Videos/RMS/20211019_233512-50mm.mkv') #50mm

frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) 
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

count = 500 #number of frames to iterate over
mkv_array = np.zeros((1080,1920,count)) #initialize array of zeros
for i in range(count):
    frame = (cap.read()) # load frame from video, returns bool value and pixel array
    a = frame[1] # want only pixel array, excludes bool value
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(a), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert from RGB to gray scale
    mkv_array[:,:,i] += gray_frame #add frames to initial array
print(mkv_array.shape)  


image_array = mkv_array[:,:,0].astype(np.float32) # first slice of a data cube
level = 5 #level above background noise

i = range(0,1080)
j = range(0,1920)
#find stars above certain threshold
for i in mkv_array[i,:,0]:
    for j in mkv_array[:,j,0]:
        bkg = sep.Background(image_array) # find background level of image array
        print(bkg.globalback)
        background = bkg.globalback #background level
        print(bkg.globalrms)
        noise = bkg.globalrms # noise in background
        if mkv_array[i,j,0] < background + level*noise: # reject stars below threshold
            continue 
        else:
            labeled, num_objects = ndimage.label(mkv_array[i,j,0]) # label stars that meet condition

        xy = np.array(ndimage.center_of_mass(image_array, labeled, range(1, num_objects+1))) #find coordinates for accepted stars
        print(xy)
        y,x = np.hsplit(xy,2)
```

The error I recieve is in my `if mkv_array[i,j,0] < background + level*noise` statement line: `` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices. ``
How can I fix this?

Comment: What are `i` and `j`? Are you sure they're integers, slices, ellipses, `np.newaxis`, `None` or integer or boolean arrays?

Comment: Basically, how is `mkv_array` defined?

Comment: @ForceBru they should be integers that represent each dimension: i= 0 to 1080, j = 0 to 1920

Comment: @Chris mkv_array is a stack of frames that ultimately is put together by the cv2. VideoCapture function. I edited my code to include this now.

Comment: @Jimbles, okay, but are they _actually_ these integers? You can `print(i, j)` before `if mkv_array[i,j,0]...` and see what's printed right before the error occurs

Comment: `mkv_array = np.zeros((1080,1920,count))` is an array of floating-point numbers

Comment: @Jimbles, what's the last output before the error happens?

Comment: @ForceBru I get two 1D arrays of pixel intensities: [87. 71. 51. ... 88. 88. 88.] [87. 71. 51. ... 88. 88. 88.] The debugger I am using tells me that they are both arrays of float64 both with sizes of (1920,). shouldn't i be (1080,) based on my dimensions?

Comment: Why does you code say `i = range(0,1080); j = range(0,1920)` before the loop? Then you proceed to _overwrite_ both `i` and `j` with `for i in ...` and `for j in ...`. So, the first iteration will look like `for i in mkv_array[range(0,1080),:,0]: for j in mkv_array[:,range(0,1920),0]:`. Are you sure you want to index `mkv_array` with these `range` objects?

Comment: @ForceBru if I don't write the statement for j = range(0,1920) I get the error ```j is undefined``` in the second ```for``` statement. It is weird because it doesn't say the same for i if I do not include the range assignment for it. I don't know how else to fix that

Comment: It doesn't say this for `i` because it actually comes from the `for i in range(count):` loop above, so it'll be using that "old" value of `i`. I think you should first understand what you're trying to do with the `for i in mkv_array[i,:,0]:` loop. Currently you'll be looping over floating-point numbers (because `mkv_array` is an array of floats) or even vectors, because `mkv_array[range(0,1080),:,0]` is a matrix.

Comment: @ForceBru ahh I see now, thank you!!

Comment: @jimbles it would be better to post your edit as an answer (yes, self-answers are fine) so you can later accept it, and the question doesn't show up as 'unanswered'

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this issue:

```
xdim = 1080
ydim = 1920
#find stars above certain threshold
star_list_x = []
star_list_y = []
for j in range(xdim): #loop through all x coordinates
    for k in range(ydim): #loop through all y coordinates
        if mkv_array[j,k,0] < threshold: #skip if below threshold

            continue 
        else:   #keep if above threshold, append to star list.
            star_list_x.append(j)
            star_list_y.append(k)

star_list = np.array(list(zip(star_list_x, star_list_y)))
```